# Sending PubSub message manually in Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, publish-subscribe, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

**How can I send a PubSub message manually (that is to say, without using a `PubsubIO`) in Dataflow ?**

Importing (via Maven) `google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all 2.5.0` already imports a version of `com.google.pubsub.v1` for which I was unable to find an easy way to send messages to a Pubsub topic (this version doesn't, for instance, allow to manipulate `Publisher` instances, which is the way described in the official documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way I found browsing https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java/blob/master/dataflow/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/StockInjector.java:

```
import com.google.api.services.pubsub.Pubsub;
import com.google.api.services.pubsub.model.PublishRequest;
import com.google.api.services.pubsub.model.PubsubMessage;
public class PubsubManager {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PubsubManager.class);
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final Pubsub pubsub = createPubsubClient();

    public static class RetryHttpInitializerWrapper implements HttpRequestInitializer {

        // Intercepts the request for filling in the "Authorization"
        // header field, as well as recovering from certain unsuccessful
        // error codes wherein the Credential must refresh its token for a
        // retry.
        private final GoogleCredential wrappedCredential;

        // A sleeper; you can replace it with a mock in your test.
        private final Sleeper sleeper;

        private RetryHttpInitializerWrapper(GoogleCredential wrappedCredential) {
            this(wrappedCredential, Sleeper.DEFAULT);
        }

        // Use only for testing.
        RetryHttpInitializerWrapper(
                GoogleCredential wrappedCredential, Sleeper sleeper) {
            this.wrappedCredential = Preconditions.checkNotNull(wrappedCredential);
            this.sleeper = sleeper;
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            final HttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler backoffHandler =
                    new HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(
                            new ExponentialBackOff())
                            .setSleeper(sleeper);
            request.setInterceptor(wrappedCredential);
            request.setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(
                    new HttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean handleResponse(HttpRequest request,
                                                      HttpResponse response,
                                                      boolean supportsRetry)
                                throws IOException {
                            if (wrappedCredential.handleResponse(request,
                                    response,
                                    supportsRetry)) {
                                // If credential decides it can handle it, the
                                // return code or message indicated something
                                // specific to authentication, and no backoff is
                                // desired.
                                return true;
                            } else if (backoffHandler.handleResponse(request,
                                    response,
                                    supportsRetry)) {
                                // Otherwise, we defer to the judgement of our
                                // internal backoff handler.
                                logger.info("Retrying " + request.getUrl());
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            request.setIOExceptionHandler(new HttpBackOffIOExceptionHandler(
                    new ExponentialBackOff()).setSleeper(sleeper));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Cloud Pub/Sub client.
     */
    private static Pubsub createPubsubClient() {
        try {
            HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
            HttpRequestInitializer initializer =
                    new RetryHttpInitializerWrapper(credential);
            return new Pubsub.Builder(transport, JSON_FACTORY, initializer).build();
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            logger.error("Could not create Pubsub client: " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Publishes the given message to a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
     */
    public static void publishMessage(String message, String outputTopic) {
        int maxLogMessageLength = 200;
        if (message.length() < maxLogMessageLength) {
            maxLogMessageLength = message.length();
        }
        logger.info("Received ...." + message.substring(0, maxLogMessageLength));

        // Publish message to Pubsub.
        PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = new PubsubMessage();
        pubsubMessage.encodeData(message.getBytes());

        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
        publishRequest.setMessages(Collections.singletonList(pubsubMessage));
        try {
            pubsub.projects().topics().publish(outputTopic, publishRequest).execute();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            logger.error("Stuff happened in pubsub: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider using [`PubsubUnboundedSink`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubUnboundedSink.html)? Quick example:

```
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubClient;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubJsonClient;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSink;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubClient.TopicPath;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage;


public class PubsubTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
                        .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class); 

        // writes message to "output_topic"
        TopicPath topic = PubsubClient.topicPathFromName(options.getProject(), "output_topic");

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        p
        .apply("input string", Create.of("This is just a message"))
        .apply("convert to Pub/Sub message", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, PubsubMessage>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                c.output(new PubsubMessage(c.element().getBytes(), null));          
            }
        }))
        .apply("write to topic", new PubsubUnboundedSink(
            PubsubJsonClient.FACTORY,
            StaticValueProvider.of(topic), // topic
            "timestamp", // timestamp attribute
            "id", // ID attribute
            5 // number of shards
        )); 

        p.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the main point of my question is to _not_ use Dataflow components. This is because I want to be able to publish pubsub messages from anywhere in my code, and I can't just connect every single stage to a pubsub source. This would not be acceptable nor in terms of code maintenance, nor in terms of the visual dataflow graph which would become very messy.

Comment: With `com.google.pubsub.v1` I have the same problem as I can't import `Publisher`. One possibility would be to play with the dependencies to exclude it from `dataflow-java-sdk-all` and import the latest version or call the API directly with an HTTP-client library

Comment: I found a workaround, will post an answer when I get some time today

Answer (score 0):

You can send pubsub message using PubsubIO writeMessages method

dataflow Pipeline steps

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
   p.apply("Transformer1", ParDo.of(new Fn.method1()))
    .apply("Transformer2", ParDo.of(new Fn.method2()))
    .apply("PubsubMessageSend", PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(PubSubConfig.getTopic(options.getProject(), options.getpubsubTopic ())));
```

Define Project Name and pubsubTopic where to want to send pub subs message in the PipeLineOptions